# Secondary ranking by elimination within in an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, ranking

I'm writing a golf ranking leaderboard based on the json example data below. I can easily rank the order from lowes (best) score to highest (worse) however when it comes to "ties" this is the issue I'm trying to figure out.

Here's a quick background: At array[0] is the final score, array[1] is the team number (T1,T2, etc) and array[2]-[10] is the sequential shots made per hole. Add up the sequential shots and subtract 36 which will equal array[0] for each team.

The tiebreakers now should be "re-ranked" according to the lowest score of each hole in sequence. For instance when comparing T11, T2 and T5... T2 should be ranked overall second because they shot 3 on the first sequential hole while T11 and T5 shot 4. Now that T2 is "re-ranked" as overall 2nd and out of the comparison, T11 would now compare with T5 for the next "re-rank" and so on for all tied teams. If anyone could give me a scenario I'm not looking for a script just basically need to temp extract the tied teams as segmented by the tied score i.e. extract T11, T2 and T5 (-5 score) for comparison and extract T10 and T9 (-4 score) as well as T!, T3, T4, and T7 (-3 score) for re-ranking then put those "re-ranked" segments back into the original array without disrupting the the teams that have not been compared in their original rank, i.e. T8 (-7 score) and T6 (-1 score).

```
{
[-7,"T8","4","3","3","4","4","2","3","3","3"],
[-5,"T11","4","3","4","4","4","3","3","3","3"],
[-5,"T2","3","3","4","4","4","3","3","4","3"],
[-5,"T5","4","4","3","4","4","3","4","3","2"],
[-4,"T10","4","3","4","4","4","2","4","4","3"],
[-4,"T9","4","3","3","4","5","3","3","3","4"],
[-3,"T1","5","3","3","4","4","3","4","4","3"],
[-3,"T3","4","3","4","4","4","3","4","4","3"],
[-3,"T4","4","3","3","4","5","3","4","3","4"],
[-3,"T7","4","4","4","4","3","3","4","4","3"],
[-1,"T6","4","3","3","4","5","4","4","4","4"]
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to add a comparison of the sequential shots portion of the array to the sort comparison function.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a[0] <=> $b[0]) ?: (array_slice($a, 2) <=> array_slice($b, 2));
});
```

The first part, `$a[0] <=> $b[0]` just compares the first element, which I assume is something like what you're already doing.

The second part, `array_slice($a, 2) <=> array_slice($b, 2)` will only be evaluated if the first part is equal because of the `?:` operator.

The array slices can be compared directly because the way arrays are compared in PHP happens to be just like the way you want to compare the sequential shots, if I understand correctly. As long as the arrays are the same size, they will just be compared one element at a time, left to right (This is described in the "Comparison with Various Types" table in the [PHP comparison operator documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)).

---

If possible, I think it would be more convenient if you could index the data by the team number instead, like

```
[
    "T8"  => [-7,"4","3","3","4","4","2","3","3","3"],
    "T11" => [-5,"4","3","4","4","4","3","3","3","3"],
    ...

]
```

Then all you'd need for the ranking would be

```
asort($data);
```

Comment: Ok I will try to implement that asap and see how it turns out. I never thought of using the team #'s as to reference the score data, Thank you.  I tried to give an upvote but received this error. Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Everything worked out perfect thanks again. Is it possible to compare the scores based on the "hardest hole"? For instance, based on the original post,lets say the last hole is the hardest then when comparing T11, T2 and T5 scores T5 would be the winner with a 2, then the first hole would be the next hardest so when comparing the remaining T11 and T2 scores, T2 would be the next winner followed by T11.  I would need to have an array that shows the "hardest hole to easiest hole rank" then loop through it somehow while looping through the tie breaking teams. Is this the right direction I'm going